# Always open links from apps in a new browser tab

Tags: browser, 3.0-honeycomb

I often catch up on feeds (twitter/facebook/rss/email) when off line. There are often web links included that I want to check out, however, as far as I can tell, Android limits each link source application to one tab and, more annoyingly, if the same app sends a second link it creates a new tab in place of the old one with no browsing history+ - so I can't just go back and forward through the links i've tried to access while off line.

Is there any way to: 
Force the browser to create a new tab for each link clicked on an app - even if it means many tabs related to the same app being open at the same time.
Or add these sites to the history of the tab (even if not loaded successfully) so I can get to them via the back button. 
Store links (ideally with information about their source) for later investigation?

Nb Since I'm on android 3 these are real tabs - with no limit to their number i've found - rather than the 8 cards/slots on earlier versions.

- I'm minded to raise this as a bug. It seems daft.

Comment: I assume you don't want to use an alternate browser?

Comment: I'd not considered it in all honesty. Do the others behave differently?

Comment: I would hope so, but I use the stock browser :P I can experiment later.

Comment: @matthew Both Opera (mobile) and firefox act as you'd expect rather than as the stock browser does (making me think it's a bug, not a feature). If I move to either though, it'll be Opera since firefox is plain ugly on a big screen.

Comment: Good. Whether a bug or a "feature" definitely ask that it be fixed/changed. (I don't like FF either.) If FF/Opera counts as a solution for you, feel free to post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments under the question, Opera mobile acts in a much more sensible manner, creating a new tab for each link clicked.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.opera.browser

Comment: Oh the joys of the ever moving android world. Opera did, the behaviour was added to the stock android browser but I'm now using Chrome for Android Beta which does it and a lot more.