# Links from Gmail all open in same Chrome tab

Tags: gmail, intents

I just noticed that when I open a link from the Gmail app (in Chrome), then go back to Gmail and click another link, it replaces the first one in Chrome. I end up with only one tab open. Is there a workaround?

I'm not sure what to search for on crbugs, or whether this would be an Android bug or a Chrome bug.

This is pretty much the same question as [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9928/always-open-links-from-apps-in-a-new-browser-tab), but it was answered with "use Opera." I like Chrome and would rather not change browsers over this, and mainly have two questions:

1. Is this intended behavior?
2. Is there an open bug against it, and if not does anyone have enough of a hunch about the root cause to point me to the right place to file it?

Comment: That issue has been reported before in Chromium project [Issue 115732: External links don't open in new tabs if multiple links are opened in Chrome Beta](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115732)

Answer (score 1):

**Q: Is there a workaround?**
**A**: Open a link from the Gmail app (goes into Chrome), open a new tab and leave it empty, then go back to Gmail and click another link, it does not replace the first one in Chrome. You end up with two non-empty tabs open. Is that a satisfactory workaround?