# How to make gmail links open in chrome, in new instance or tab?

Tags: chrome-for-android, gmail

My question is like this one, but it's 10 years old:

[Links from Gmail all open in same Chrome tab](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36287/links-from-gmail-all-open-in-same-chrome-tab)

I would like to be able to open links from gmail in chrome and have it not blow away what I already have there.  That would be either a new tab or a new instance of chrome.

Can it be done?  I have a Pixel 3, so hopefully something hot off the presses is not needed.

Comment: "*have it not blow away what I already have there*" could you explain more about this? I assume you have turned off "Open web links in Gmail" (which [was not there before 2016](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145745/44325)) from the General settings so that links are opened in the (Chrome) browser directly. However, when I tried opening links with that option turned off, Chrome opens the links from Gmail in new tabs normally.

Comment: Yes, I have gmail set to open in chrome instead of its internal browser.  In my case, if I have Chrome open with some web site displayed, when I click a link in gmail, it simply replaces what I had open with the thing from gmail.